# Inner Loop starts at i + 1 relationship to sum of integers

Tags: big-o

According to the "Cracking the Coding Interview" book by Gayle Laakmann McDowdell a loop like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {

    }
}
```

has a runtime of `O(n^2)`. This is because it is reduced from `N(N-1)/2`. The book gives examples of the "Sum of integers", where the rule is `N(N+1)/2` as evidence.

I think I understand from the book's examples how the `N(N+1)/2` works. You get a series of numbers:

`1, 2, 3, 4`

and pair the low values with the high ones;

`1 + 4 = 5`

`2 + 3 = 5`

The result `5 = 4 + 1` hence the `N + 1`
As we have created two groups from the series we want to multiply by half the length of N:
`N + 1 * N/2`

I can't seem to apply this logic of adding low and high numbers to the numbers created by the loop and get n - 1. If N was 5 the inner loop would run

`4 (times), 3 (times), 2 (times), 1 (time)`

With these descending numbers I can't see how the pairing rule above fits in with this to get `n - 1`? Is there a pairing rule? How is `n - 1` derived?

Comment: I think I now got what you meant by "pairing" and have updated my answer accordingly. Does that answer your question now?

Comment: Yes totally, my maths is diabolical, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you pairing the numbers? It's really much more straightforward than that. Let `n = array.length`.

The inner loop has `n-1` iterations in the first iteration of the outer loop, then `n-2` iterations in the second iteration of the outer loop etc. So the total number of steps is `(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1`. Which of course is `n(n-1)/2`.

---

#### Update

I thought it was clear that `1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1) / 2` from high school maths. But here is an explanation.

You can formally prove the result using mathematical induction. But you can also give an intuitive and informal derivation (this is what you called "pairing") - the story goes that the young Carl Friedrich Gauss came up with this when he was in primary school:

```
1     +   2   + ... + (n-1) +   n   = x
n     + (n-1) + ... +   2   +   1   = x  (just the first line in reverse)
(n+1) + (n+1) + ... + (n+1) + (n+1) = 2x (adding the first two lines)
                             n(n+1) = 2x (counting the (n+1)'s)
                           n(n+1)/2 = x  (dividing both sides by 2)
```

Now what if we only want to count up to `n-1`? If you wanted to, you could do the same trick again to derive the sum:

```
  1   +   2   + ... + (n-2) + (n-1) = x
(n-1) + (n-2) + ... +   2   +   1   = x  (just the first line in reverse)
  n   + n     + ... +   n   +   n   = 2x (adding the first two lines)
                             (n-1)n = 2x (counting the n's)
                           n(n-1)/2 = x  (dividing both sides by 2)
```

But actually that's far too tedious. Since you know that `1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2`, you can just substitute `n-1` for `n` in this formula and immediately get `n(n-1)/2`.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. The pairing of the numbers is used in the book to display why `N(N+1)/2` equals the sum of integers 1 through N but it isn't clear how this explanation relates to `N(N-1)/2`. I'm wondering if this rule does not relate to `N(N-1)/2` at all and `N(N-1)/2` is the sum of negative integers just because it is, and that's that.